# wordpress get posts with join custom table

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, post-meta

i have created table in wordpress like this

```
/////////////////////////////////////
| id  |   postid  | userid | rating |
| 1   |   ahmed   | 20     | 5      |
| 2   |   john    | 13     | 3      |
| 3   |   sara    | 49     | 10     |
/////////////////////////////////////
```

and my post has meta key called total_rating
so i need to get posts with meta key and custom table
if ahmed logged in he should get all posts are belong to him in custom table 
i use this to get my data

```
$guide = array(
'post_type' => 'ratings',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
   array(
     'key' => 'total_rating',
     'compare' => 'EXISTS'
   ), 
   array(
      'taxonomy' => 'new_cats',
      'field'    => 'id',
      'terms'    => array(11,19),
   )
),
);
```

and my question is how to add custom table to this array above
like

> if(post and post have meta key and post have taxonomy(11,19) and post
>   have my custom table postid) then display the results